# How Long is the Google Play Application Review Period?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I submitted an app for public release via the Google Play Console. Current status Under review. How many days/weeks is the review period usually? It's been under review for a week.

Comment: It should not take that long. I've seen things get inexplicably hung up like that both in Google and in Apple's play store. What has worked for me is to do another build and resubmit.